# How do you make a modal view appear outside of a controller?

Tags: swift

I am trying to program a little game just to apply the concepts I learned in this course myself. When the game opens up, I would like for a custom modal view to tell the user how to play. Likewise, when they lose, I want to present a results page, which would be inside an if statement. I've searched all over the internet, and I can't find a way to display these views without an error. All that this video shows is how to show a display a view when a button is pressed; how do I display a custom modal view on command in code? (I am very new to Swift, so try to put it in layman's terms.) Thanks!

```
import UIKit
var numberValue = 0
let randomInt = getRandomNumber()

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HowToPlayView") as! HowToPlay

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }





    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        numberValue += 1
        updateButtonValue(buttonLabel)
    }



}


    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        numberValue += 1
        updateButtonValue(buttonLabel)
    }



}
```

That's my view controller. Getting error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

[My view in interface and connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YddWp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmMoZ.png)

Comment: What line is getting the error?

Comment: Are you getting this error in the ViewController Class or are you getting it in the HowToPlay Class?

Comment: I am getting it on the line in HowToPlay that says: self.presentViewController(htp, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: move your code to present your vc from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try a different approach to solve this issue. Above your ViewController you should see three different buttons like this: [image]

Click on the first button and Ctrl + Drag to the view that you want to display and choose display modally. After that is done you should see this arrow appear: [image]

This is called the *segue* from the first view to the second view and you can call this in your code to transition from one view to the next, but first we have to give our *segue* an identifier. You can do this by clicking on the arrow and a window should come up like this:
[image]

As you can see you will have to fill out the identifier field, and in my case I just named it "myAwesomeSegue".

Lastly, in the first ViewController run this code when you need to present the next view controller:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("myAwesomeSegue", sender: nil)
```

*Please note that if you use this method just delete the previous code you had before as this is a brand new approach (so basically delete this code):*

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HowToPlayView") as! HowToPlay

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Final code for the firstViewController:
[image]

Comment: Edit: I tried this, and I got no error, but the view didn't appear.

Comment: Ya, I think it's probably something else causing this issue. I tested it out and it should work.

Comment: Do I put it in HowToPlay or ViewController?

Comment: Put it in View Controller (the one that you are presenting from)

Comment: Also, do you mind pasting the full SIGABRT error here for me? Let me take a look at it again.

Comment: 2016-05-22 19:25:49.748 Frustration[8955:362545] Warning: Attempt to present <Frustration.HowToPlay: 0x7f822a4195f0> on <Frustration.ViewController: 0x7f822a415a90> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Aha, I think you are calling the code to early. Try putting it in viewDidAppear not viewDidLoad like this: `override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("myAwesomeSegue", sender: nil) //The segue name should be whatever you put in the identifier field.
    }`

Comment: Ya you have to manually type it out. It doesn't come typed in. Just copy and paste the code above and then change the segue identifier name to whatever you named it.

Comment: Oh dear. I pasted in that code and it gave me a ton of errors in other lines.

Comment: Did you paste it in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Paste it outside of ViewDidLoad.

Comment: No. Was I supposed to?

Comment: Yeah I did. It's telling me that all the other functions don't need override now.

Comment: Hmm.. could you add a picture inside your question for me so I could take a look?

Comment: There it is with no description

Comment: At the end of line 23 just add a "}". Hopefully that should fix the error.

Comment: It worked! But now every time I press the button to dismiss it it comes back up again.

Comment: Ok, so create an @IBAction for the button that is supposed to dismiss the view controller. Then in the @IBAction you will want to run this code `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I am assuming that the "Start" button is supposed to dismiss the view. So create an @IBAction by using Ctrl+Drag and then run the code above.

Comment: I already have that code. It is getting dismissed for a second, but then reappearing.

Comment: Oh, I think I know why. Since we are calling it in the viewDidAppear every time the view appears it will present the HowToPlay View.

Comment: Do you want to present this only on first launch so only the first time the user opens the app it will present, but the next time the user opens the app it won't present.

Comment: Okay. How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe. Whichever's easier; honestly, they would both function well, since it's how to play.

Comment: Ok let's do it only on the first app launch. But honestly this might be too much for just the comments section. How about you ask one more question, and then I will answer it there.

Comment: I can only post once every 90 minutes. How about you make a post...?

Comment: Just post it in the other question.